# How to create custom URL user friendly?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a very peculiar requirement, hopefully I can explain it without being too confusing. I created a page template where I list some state's city, let's say the URL is like this: `http://www.example.com/states/?q=ohio`

and i would like to do it like `http://www.example.com/states/ohio/`

i also used **`add_rewrite_rule`** but it's does not given me output that i want.

so how could i do fix ?

Comment: Are you running Nginx or Apache?

Comment: Apache and my site in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not PHP, it's apache using mod_rewrite. What happens is the person requests the link, http://www.example.com/states/ohio/ and then apache chops it up using a rewrite rule making it look like this, http://www.example.com/states/?q=ohio, to the server. You can find more here: [Rewrite Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Comment: That depends on if they're using Apache or Nginx. A good answer though, but to improve it, you should give an example rewrite rule as per OPs requirements with comments/explanation on what's happening

Answer (score 0):

#### Web server side

Since you're running Apache, you can create a [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) to rewrite the URI to something that the application understands but have vanity/pretty URIs to your endusers.

For example;

```
RewriteEngine On

#Rewrites a request like http://www.example.com/states/ohio/ to http://www.example.com/states/?q=ohio at application level
#Having the /? at the end makes the ending slash optional
RewriteRule ^states/([^\/]+)/?$ /states/?q=$1 [L]
```

<sup>Tested with http://htaccess.mwl.be/</sup>

#### Wordpress side

You can use [`add_rewrite_rule`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) to rewrite the URLs as you desire

```
add_rewrite_rule('^states/([^\/]+)/?$', 'states/?q=ohio$matches[1]', 'top');
```

Otherwise, you'd have to manually modify each `href` element on an anchor tag (`<a />`) to point to `/states/ohio/` instead of `/states/?q=ohio`.

Comment: I used above code in .htaccess file but stile ?q is appearing in URL.

Comment: The RewriteRule rewrites it for the application level, it won't rewrite URLs from the application, which is why you need to add the rewrite rule on the wordpress side as well using `add_rewrite_rule()`.